# android studio 2020.3.1 meets res.srcDirs error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

android studio in 2020.3.1 meets this error, however it can run successfully. in lower android studio version such as 3.6, the error gone.

in build.gradle:

```
sourceSets {
main {
    res.srcDirs = [
            'src/main/res',
            'src/main/res/layout',
            'src/main/res/layout/test'
    ]
}
```

}

as picture show:
[Snipaste-2022-01-24-17-56-36.png](https://postimg.cc/yDMRggkN)

Comment: There is no error text on the attached screenshot. Please add the exact error text and the code snippet where it occurs.

Comment: yes, There is no error text  in whole screen,  very strange

Comment: please upload all relevant information to this site rather than referring/linking somewhere else

Comment: Likely the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/a/72377150/246914.  Android Studio no longer supports sharing within a module with srcDirs.  It now requires a module to share code.