# Duplicate content roots detected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sqldelight

Android Studio gives me the following error code after I copied my project.

```
Duplicate content roots detected: Path [/home/addi/AndroidStudioProjects/appfolder/appname/app/build/generated/sqldelight/code/Database/debug] of module [appname.app.main] was removed from modules [appname.app.main]
```

the "original" project doesn't show that error

SQL delight version 1.5.3
android studio chipmuck 2021.2.1

Comment: See https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/1894

Comment: the problem is still existing after adding Sonatype's snapshots repository.

Comment: Any solution for this? I'm getting the same error...

Comment: I get it works by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72377150/1083128

Answer (score 5):

There was a behaviour change in Android Studio Chipmunk that caused this.

Here is the related issue logged against Android Studio. It is apparently fixed in Dolphin.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232007221

And here is the one for JetBrains (which seems much older).

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210908/Do-not-auto-remove-duplicate-content-roots-detected

Comment: I am facing same issue in Dolphin. I updated Chipmunk to Dolphin. It isn't a fresh install.

Comment: It is still present in Dolphin. Fresh install.

Comment: facing in Electric Eel

Comment: Facing in Flamingo

Comment: Facing in Giraffe..

Comment: Facing in Hedgehog

Comment: it is not coming from Android Studio. In my case it is coming from moko-resources library for KMM

Comment: @KJNewtown Did you find a way to fix this warning?

Comment: @PhilippFahlteich I still have the warning but I am still on an old version of moko-resources and my project is not ready to update it. Are you also using moko? Did you try using the latest moko version?
The path in my warning is this one: [myApp/shared/build/generated/moko/androidMain/assets]

Comment: Facing in Iguana